# why I have scientific notation in php concatenation

Tags: php, rest, integer-overflow

I have to call to an endpoint of an API Restful where the last element is the resource id

http://midomain.com/resurces/:resourceID

The resourceId is 666769510661446146 but when I concact this number to the url

```
$url = "http://midomain.com/resources/" . $myId;
```

Php returns http://midomain.com/resources/6.6676951066145E+17

I try to fix casting the number to double and using sprintf but always it's the same

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think `$resourceId` is what you think it is. Where does it come from and what have you done with it before this?

Comment: Because the value is too large for a 32-bit signed integer, so it has to be represented as float. Wherever you get this value from, make sure you treat it as a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `number_format`?

```
$url = "http://midomain.com/resources/" . number_format($myId,0,"","");
```

This way you will avoid scientific representation. Take a look to the [official documentation](http://php.net/number_format) for more info

You can see an [example here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3ff182d8ed04f3687d1c150d830f70e138ce1848)